# Explain cURL strange chunked response

Tags: curl

I have spent many hours searching the internet trying to understand the response I am getting without any luck.

When I run the curl command:

```
curl http://www.server.com/ajax.php?action=bike&make=3
```

I get this strange response with chunked encoding:

```
[1] 8715
[2] 8716
[3] 8717
[4] 8718
[5] 8719
[2]   Done                    make=3 

<table>

</table>
```

I am trying to automate loading web page and from [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I see the correct result (table tag is not empty) when the browser sends the request. I would like to understand why when I send the request using cURL it does not work.
What is the meaning of the [number] list I see in the response ?
Are these the chunks? If so, how can I read them?

Another thing is that the cURL command print the above response and does not return back to the shell/terminal as if it is waiting for user input, so I can type anything and only when I hit enter, the control goes back to the main shell/terminal.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

heh heh bash is interpreting your ampersand. URL needs quotes.

Comment: quotes fixed it! Thanks so much :)